# Is PHP DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED broken?

Tags: php, datetime, php-7, datetime-format

I can't seem to get `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to work in PHP 7.0.26

My code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$t = '2018-02-23T11:29:16.434Z';
echo '$t: ' . json_encode($t) . PHP_EOL;
$f = DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED;
echo '$f: ' . json_encode($f) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'createFromFormat: ' . json_encode(DateTime::createFromFormat($f, $t)) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'getLastErrors: ' . json_encode(DateTime::getLastErrors()) . PHP_EOL;

$t = '2018-02-23T11:29:16.434+00:00';
echo '$t: ' . json_encode($t) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'createFromFormat: ' . json_encode(DateTime::createFromFormat($f, $t)) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'getLastErrors: ' . json_encode(DateTime::getLastErrors()) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
$t: "2018-02-23T11:29:16.434Z"
$f: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.vP"
createFromFormat: false
getLastErrors: {"warning_count":0,"warnings":[],"error_count":2,"errors":{"20":"The format separator does not match","21":"The timezone could not be found in the database"}}
$t: "2018-02-23T11:29:16.434+00:00"
createFromFormat: false
getLastErrors: {"warning_count":0,"warnings":[],"error_count":2,"errors":{"20":"The format separator does not match","21":"The timezone could not be found in the database"}}
```

I note that "v" is not listed in the values for the format parameter for [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters)  --  but supposedly I should be able to use the const `DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED` which includes a "v".   It also says that [this const was added in version 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339_extended)

Comment: You took note of http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#121431 already?

Comment: @CBroe - No, I didn't see that it was waaaaay down the page. Thanks - put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Happy enough with Alex' answer, he even looked into the details a bit more,  so you might as well accept that one ;-)

Comment: Yes it is. The "v" portion is not even in the docs so it cannot be parsed back. It seems it should be "u". Go figure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As CBroe noted, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#121431) is the right solution for you. You should use `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP` instead of `DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED`, which is `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP", "2018-02-23T11:29:16.434Z"); //works
```

I actually went to take a look why this is happening, and here's what I found.

There is a [closed bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69089) requesting support for RFC3339 with milliseconds. The bug author created a [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1103) to add this feature. But whilst he created a `RFC3339_EXTENDED` constant for the `format` function, he did not add the support for `createFromFormat`. If you take a look [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3152d44b361ce528368ca4f57111315b2fa324bd/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re#L1943), there is no support for `v` option (which is milliseconds). So yeah.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, apparently it only got fixed in PHP 7.3.0, see this https://3v4l.org/4nMi4

[image]